# How to register a theme function from the theme

Tags: 7, theming

I want to introduce a custom theme function in my theme.  Typically, I would register a theme in `hook_theme()` in a module, but I want to define this function from my theme (Omega 4).  In whatever module I'm in, I'd like to just build my render array and let it be themed by the theme-side theme function.

Example:

```
$ra = array(
    '#theme' => 'my_theme_fx',
    '#somevar' => 'foo',
    '#anothervar' => 'bar'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of `hook_theme()` is:

> Register a module (or theme's) theme implementations.

So you can implement this hook in your theme.